# how to search content in search bar without press a button in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I want search content in my search bar without press search buttons means when i enter any text in search bar automatically search filter the content when i clear or cancel search then show my main content list here i implement code for search bar

```
-(void)SearchBarCode
{ 
    self.disableViewOverlay.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    self.disableViewOverlay.alpha = 0;
    theSearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-61, 46, 378.0f, 50)];
    theSearchBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    UIView *searchBarView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 46, 310.0, 44.0)];
    searchBarView.autoresizingMask = 0;
    theSearchBar.delegate =self;
    [searchBarView addSubview:theSearchBar];
    self.navigationItem.title=@"Insta SMS Collection";
    self.navigationItem.titleView=searchBarView;
    theSearchBar.placeholder = @"Search";
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.theSearchBar resignFirstResponder];
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    theSearchBar.showsScopeBar = YES;
    [theSearchBar invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
    [theSearchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [theSearchBar invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
    [theSearchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = TRUE;
    theSearchBar.text = @"";

    theSearchBar.text = @"";
    [theSearchBar setShowsCancelButton: NO animated: YES];
    [theSearchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)searchTableList
{
    NSString *searchString = theSearchBar.text;
    filteredContentList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (SMSCategory *cat in Arrayobject)
    {
        NSString *tempStr = cat.Name;
        NSComparisonResult result = [tempStr compare:searchString options: (NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, 
        [searchString length])];
        if (result == NSOrderedSame)
        {
            [filteredContentList addObject:cat];
        }
    }
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = TRUE;

    [theSearchBar resignFirstResponder];
    [theSearchBar setShowsCancelButton: NO animated: YES];

    [self searchTableList];
    [self DynamicButton:filteredContentList];
    [self viewDidAppear:true];
}
```

**.h File** Code

```
@interface CategoryMainWindowViewController : UIViewController<UISearchBarDelegate,UITextViewDelegate>{
    NSMutableArray *Arrayobject;
    UIView *disableViewOverlay;
    UITableView *theTableView;
    UISearchBar *theSearchBar;
    NSMutableArray *filteredContentList;
    BOOL isSearching;
}

@property(retain) UIView *disableViewOverlay;
@property(retain) NSMutableArray *Arrayobject;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *theTableView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISearchBar *theSearchBar;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSString *databasePath;

-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar activate:(BOOL) active;
-(void)DynamicButton:(NSMutableArray*)objectName;
-(NSMutableArray*)GetData;

@end
```

Comment: Please note the changes I have made to your code format. Please keep it like this when posting questions to stackoverflow. Also methods start with a lowerCase, `DynamicButton:` should be `dynamicButton:`. You haven't listed anything that you have tried either, you have simply posted your existing code saying you want to do something else, what have you tried?

Comment: With the DidBeginEditing it'd just search once. What he wants (as far as I can tell ofcourse) is to search everytime the user enters / changes text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **theSearchBar.text** in the delegate methods, searchBarTextDidEndEditing OR 
searchBar:textDidChange:

Answer (score 2):

You can implement the delegate-method

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText;
```

This will be called every time the user enters a character. You then just have to search with the given string.

For example you could call the method, that is called when clicking search itself:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{
    [self searchBarSearchButtonClicked:searchBar];
}
```

Comment: how to code for cancel buttons  means when my search finish i want press cancel button to go main content list

Comment: when i press cancel its go to initial state

Comment: I'd have done the same as you do in your searchBarCancelButtonClicked-method. Does it get called? What happens?

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint inside your method? Does it halt on the breakpoint?

Comment: But other delegate methods such as textDidBeginEditing/EndEditing are called? Put a breakpoint there too.

Comment: When what you say is true, that no delegate-method is called at ALL, what happens when you press search? Is anything of your code even called? Your code is very "ugly" (no offense), you really should pay more attention to formatting and more. For example its really bad-practise to call [self viewDidAppear] by code.

Comment: when i press search its search content but after search finish i want cancel that search its not work

Comment: please help me last 2 days i doing that

Comment: So the method searchBarSearchButtonClicked is called? When you put a breakpoint there, it halts on the breakpoint?

Comment: problem is that after enter first text in search bar  keyboard will be disappear . again i want touch a search bar to enter second text

Comment: You are asking a hundred questions at once, I've no idea where to start, neither do I understand what your problem is. I'm sorry but you have to specify exactly WHAT you want and then provide code for it. I can't just guess where your problem lies.

Comment: i fixed this problem is that after enter first text in search bar  keyboard will be disappear . again i want touch a search bar to enter second text

Comment: Then just tap the search bar again and enter your text?

Comment: yes but i want constant keyboard until my search not completed suppose i want to search key "AN" then 2 time i want to press search . i want this at only one time press

Comment: Then remove the following line from searchBarSearchButtonClicked: [theSearchBar resignFirstResponder];

Comment: @ChetanGharat If you have a new issue, then you should ask a new question.  Coming back after several days and asking TMob questions when you have already accepted another answer isn't the way we do things on this site.

Comment: @TMob please check my auto layout for buttons

Answer (score 1):

> assign Arrdata to ArrTemp in viewdidload mehod then use this method for searching if search field contains empty text then it will display main content who stored in ArrTemp previously.....

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
ArrTemp = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:Arrdata];
```

}

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    if (searchText.length >0) {
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate
                                  predicateWithFormat:@"vName CONTAINS[cd] %@ OR vName LIKE[cd] %@",
                                  searchText,searchText];//
        NSArray *filteredArray = [Arrdata filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
        Arrdata = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:filteredArray];

    }else{
        Arrdata = ArrTemp;
    }
    [tblview reloadData];
```

}